# Audio ADC - grounding problem

Tags: audio, adc, grounding

I searched through the internet but couldn't find an answer to my question. Maybe I just don't know what to search for.

I want to convert an audio signal coming from a stage box from analog to digital. I found some integrated circuits which seem to be suited just for that (like [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm1803a.pdf?ts=1592066760158&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)).

But here is the problem. The audio signal coming from the stage box is referenced to the wall plug ground. Which means that the audio signal oscillates between negative and positive voltages. But the analog-digital converter I linked works only for positive input voltages. I found that there are also some ADCs (like [this one](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2000968.pdf?_ga=2.198627119.1066644570.1592062864-445927383.1591722977&_gac=1.141830406.1592066749.EAIaIQobChMI0Kb0y5L_6QIVkkMYCh08zwe3EAQYAyABEgJX5fD_BwE)) which seem to be able to handle also negative voltages. But is it the best solution? Is there some way to "lift" the audio signal potential so that it oscillates only in positive voltage range?

Thank you in advance for all your suggestions.

Comment: Assuming you have a single digitized audio mono signal, what are you doing with it?

Comment: I'd like to send it over WiFi. But I didn't include this information in the question because it seemed like it wouldn't help to answer it, would it?

Comment: An ADC has to be picked that suits the digital interface too.

Comment: **All** pure analogue audio signals have positive and negative signal perturbations. This isn't anything to do with the earth on the stage box power feed **BUT** isolation may be really needed if you are hoping to transport the digitized signal to another part of the studio/stage.

Comment: Well, you can either use local ground at the stage and subsequently digitally isolate the transmission before shipping it off somewhere else. Hold-on, will the WiFi transmitter be located at the ADC and it's associated MCU?

Comment: Yes, the WiFi is meant to be located on the same PCB as the ADC and MCU. The thing here is not the digitzed signal transission. The thing is how to sample a signal which goes to both positive and negative voltage levels...and the ADC can handle only positive voltages.

Comment: Audio signals are typically AC coupled before many processing steps. Assuming you have the correct gain in the original signal you should be able to introduce an AC coupling capacitor to "re-center" your signal as the ADC requires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PCM1803A shows you how to couple audio signals (see red box below): -

[image]

All you have to do is ensure the signal doesn't exceed 3 volts p-p or you will clip the digital conversion. Also tied in with this are strict requirements to ensure that excessive voltages are not present at the input that could damage the ADC but, this is common to any type of ADC.

So, you need to match and condition any audio signal to suit the ADC. If the source is differential or balanced then you need an op-amp circuit to convert it to single ended and that op-amp circuit can give you the protection to the PCM chip. You might also need TVS diodes to protect the op-amp but that's a necessary evil that any circuit has to cope with.

Regards WiFi transmission - you may not be aware that it may not produce a contiguous data-stream and that there may be a significant delay required at the receiving end in order to join things up for audio reconstruction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But why then they say in the datasheet that the absolute maximum rating (page 4) of the analog input voltage is -0.3V to Vcc+0.3V? My understanding of the red boxed schematic is that the input signal coming to the PCM1803A will still exceed the -0.3V limit.

Comment: The analogue input (full scale) is 3 volts p-p as I said in my answer and as shown on page 4 section 6.3 of the data sheet. Because it centres Vref at half Vcc this means the signal seen at the chips pins can be as high as 4 volts and as low as 1 volt - this bias is coped with automatically by the chip.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I see. You're right. But what then the absolute minimum voltage of -0.3V on the analog input pin means?

Comment: It means you can exceed the 3 volt p-p but don't exceed it by much i.e. **DO** drive the inputs with an op-amp buffer that uses the same supply as the chip. The buffer output cannot therefore reach or exceed the danger limits. The op-amp must also use a mid-rail generator to bias the signals it takes and outputs to the right mid-range DC level.

Comment: I'm sorry for deleting my last comment but I either didn't read your comment carefully or you edited it. So I just want to make sure I understand what you mean with the op-amp. Is [this](https://crcit.net/c/b187e792e89b41f587a5c39f885b0c54) something you meant? (the op-amp and the PCM1803A will be powered non-symmetrically with 0V and 5V)

Comment: Yes, that’s the type of circuit. You will also likely need to protect the op-amp input using a resistor in series with the input capacitor to limit external surge currents (maybe 4.7 kohm).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a problem. The audio is AC coupled to the PCM1803 chip input, just look at the example schematics in the datasheet. The PCM1803 applies a 2.5V bias to the input analog signal so that it doesn't go below 0V if the 3Vpp condition for the input singal is met. AC coupling capacitor ensures that the 2.5V bias does not interfere with the audio signal source.

I would not use the Maxim part for audio.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I thought about it but I don't understand the point about AC coupling. AC coupling removes the DC part of the signal, right? Thus makes the signal to oscillate around 0V. But I wanted the exact opposite. I wanted the signal to oscillate around let's say 2.5V so that it is suitable for the ADC, which can only convert positive voltage levels. Or did I misunderstood your point?

Comment: Use a voltage divider to put a 2.5VDC bias on the input of the ADC.

Comment: Well, I could do that if I wanted to sample a microphone signal which is a floating source but the thing is that the signal from the stage box is referenced to a wall plug ground and putting 2.5V on the ADC input would cause a ground loop, wouldn't it?

Comment: The PCM1803 is an audio chip. It is meant for audio. It sets the input DC bias by itself to whatever it wants. Supa Nova is wrong and did not check the datasheet - you must not set the PCM1803 DC bias externally yourself. Ground loop is another thing, it is present or absent completely separately from the AC coupling, and depends on where you ground the ADC power supply.

Comment: Ok, that would make sense. But why then they say in the datasheet that the absolute maximum rating (page 4) of the analog input voltage is -0.3V to Vcc+0.3V? If it was like you just wrote, I would expect there to be something like: analog input voltage range is -2.5V to 2.5V.

Comment: Because those voltage limits are the limits of the chip side of the capacitor, not the voltage at audio connector. Besides, those are the absolute maximum limits after which it gets destroyed. The full scale audio amplitude is typically 3Vpp, which means -1.5V to +1.5V before it starts clipping.